# not understanding why baseadapter class is extended and where the methods come from?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-adapter

Please refer to the below code
In that I cannot understand why to extend BaseAdapter class and also this getcount,getitem,getview methods are not present in the BaseAdapter class.

```
public class Customadapter extends BaseAdapter{


public int getCount() {

    return amount.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {


    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {


    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

Answer (score 1):

`BaseAdapter` class implements `ListAdapter` and `SpinnerAdapter` classes.('`implements`' keyword is used to implement an interface)

`ListAdapter` extends `Adapter` interface. (`extends` keyword is mainly used to extend a class i.e. to create a subclass)

`Adapter` interface contains `getItem()`,`getItemId()` and `getView()` methods.
Alternatively, you can use `public class Customadapter implements Adapter {}`. But the problem is you should override all the methods declared inside the `Adapter` interface.

Moreover, by extending to the `BaseAdapter` class, you can use many methods like `notifyDataSetChanged()` and `isEmpty()`, which is essential and useful in many scenarios.

Refer to this official documentation about `BaseAdapter` for more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter